# how to wrap jquery html object variable

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with html object variable

```
var loading = $('<div class="loading" style="display:none">loading...</div');
```

later on I need to wrap the object in another div with some custom styles

```
var animateWrapper = $('<div style="width:' + elwidth + '; position:absolute; top:'+elPos.top+'; left:' + elPos.left + '">' + loading.html() + '</div>');
```

Irregardless of whether I declare `animaterWrapper` and then append `loading` or or try wrapping `loading.wrap()` with the wrapper div where loading should be is always empty.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted, so the actual problem can be corrected :)

Comment: If you want to add it inside another element, use `append`. If you want to add a wrapper around existing objects use `wrap` or `wrapAll`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery append:

```js
var div = jQuery("<div></div>",{class:"my_class", text: "my div"});
var container = jQuery("<div></div>",{id: "conainer", text:"container my div"});
container.append(div);
jQuery("body").append(container);
```

```css
#conainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#conainer > .my_class {
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial HTML is invalid (missing a closing `>` on `</div'`).

Instead construct the elements using the neater jQuery object property way (less error prone):

```
var loading = $('<div>', { class: "loading", style: "display:none" }).html("loading...");
var animateWrapper = $('<div>', {style: "width:" + elwidth + "; position:absolute; top:"+elPos.top+"; left:" + elPos.left});
```

If you want to add it inside another element, use append. If you want to add a wrapper around existing objects use wrap or wrapAll

**"wrap" example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/y4460cwj/3/

Note: *I added an extra wrapper class to add styling so you could see the result is correct without DOM inspection.*

Answer (score 0):

you can create a js object using a html string.

use your wrapper html to create a new wrapper js object and then append your loading text into this.

```
//your wrapper div
var animateWrapper = '<div style="width:'+elwidth+'; position:absolute; top:'+elPos.top+'; left:'+elPos.left+'"></div>';

//your loading html
var loadingHtml = '<div class="loading" style="display:none">loading...</div>';

//wrapper div js object
var $animateWrapper = jQuery.parseHTML(animateWrapper);

//now you can append your loading text to this $animateWrapper 
$animateWrapper.append(loadingHtml);
```

you can get html of the whole wrapper div by using $animateWrapper.html(); which will have your loading html inside it.

let me know if this works..